# How to scrape links from Wikipedia with Python

Tags: python, hyperlink, screen-scraping, wikipedia, scrape

I am trying to scrape all the Links to battles from the "List of Naval Battles" on Wikipedia using python. The trouble is that I cannot figure out how to export all of the links containing the words "/wiki/Battle" to my CSV file. I am used to C++, so python is kind of foreign to me.  Any ideas?
Here is what I have so far...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

rootUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_naval_battles"


def get_soup(url,header):
    return
BeautifulSoup(
    urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)),'html.parser')

# soup settings    
url = rootUrl + item
header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}

soup = get_soup(url,header)

battle = soup.findAll("/wiki/Battle")
```

Comment: what does this give you? what were you expecting? From your question it sounds as if you have got the links and are asking how to write it as a csv, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Look up some examples of the findAll method. You can grab all of the links by looking for a elements on the page.  Once you have all of those, you can iterate over them and look at the href in the attrs and look for ones that look like "/wiki/Battle".

Comment: What other fields do you want to capture in your csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_naval_battles")
soup = bs(res.text, "html.parser")
naval_battles = {}
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    url = link.get("href", "")
    if "/wiki/Battle" in url:
        naval_battles[link.text.strip()] = url

print(naval_battles)
```