# How to scrape links from faceit

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape code from a faceit room, this is what i've tried but it doesn't work.
Any help is much appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.faceit.com/en/csgo/room/1-8d6729b5-cfeb-4059-8894-3b07e04e76b2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
extracted_link = soup.find_all('href', class_='list-unstyled')
print(extracted_link)
```

Example Link : https://www.faceit.com/en/csgo/room/1-8d6729b5-cfeb-4059-8894-3b07e04e76b2

Example Link Extracted : https://demos-europe-west2.faceit-cdn.net/csgo/f9eadb47-aea5-4672-9499-4f457c7d28bd.dem.gz

Example : https://paste.pics/AQBQY

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scrape links from Wikipedia with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326991/how-to-scrape-links-from-wikipedia-with-python)

Comment: @UmairMubeen That has no connection..

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the contents of the page is loaded dynamically, which means that `BeautifulSoup` won't see it. So you actually might be better off using `selenium` with a `webdriver` in `headless` mode.

For example:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.faceit.com/en/csgo/room/1-8d6729b5-cfeb-4059-8894-3b07e04e76b2"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.match-vs .btn-default')
print(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

Output:

```
https://demos-europe-west2.faceit-cdn.net/csgo/f9eadb47-aea5-4672-9499-4f457c7d28bd.dem.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using only `requests`:

```
import requests as r

room_id = '1-8d6729b5-cfeb-4059-8894-3b07e04e76b2'
link = 'https://api.faceit.com/match/v2/match/'+room_id

res = r.get(link)
data = res.json()
extracted_links = data['payload']['demoURLs']
print(extracted_links)
```

The code probes their `API` to get all the data at once as `JSON`, then just extract the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, FACEIT offers an API, documentation can be found here: https://developers.faceit.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34833009)